# Calculating the distance between Detector and Double Slit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, visible-light, interference, diffraction

I have a little problem that is kind of confusing me at the moment.
The following task:

> Light of the wavelength $\lambda = 500nm$ hits a double slit whose distance is $a = 30\mu m$. Each is $a = 1\mu m$ wide. On the detector the distance from the first minima to the center is $y' = 1.5 cm$. How big is the distance between double slit and detector?

Well first of all I assume that the minima caused by single slit diffraction. So I get the formula

$$d \frac{y'}{L} = n\lambda \Leftrightarrow L = \frac{dy'}{n\lambda}$$

When I insert the given values I get a distance of just $3cm$. Which clearly is unrealistic. Because when I calculate the distance of the first minima cause by double slit diffraction using

$$a \frac{y'}{L} = \left(n - \frac{1}{2}\right)\lambda \Leftrightarrow y' = \frac{L}{a}\left(n - \frac{1}{2}\right)\lambda $$

I get $y' < 1.5cm$ which does not make sense... So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angle of the first diffracted beam (assuming we are talking about double slit, and not worrying about the width of the single slit) is

$$\alpha=\frac{\lambda}{d}$$

Then we find the distance from

$$\frac{spacing}{distance}=\alpha$$

So

$$distance = spacing \frac{d}{\lambda}=1.5cm\frac{30\mu}{500nm}=0.9m$$

Diagram:

[image]

Comment: Hey thank you. But I am just wondering why the information about the with of the single slit s given. May it really be that it has no use in this task?

Comment: Yes - you don't need the slit width. It would not be the first time that you get "more information than you need". This is how the real world works. You have information - but you don't know what you need to use. It's great for multiple choice questions - you give a few extra numbers, and each answer is a "vaguely plausible" combination of numbers. It is up to you to choose what information to use.

Comment: Well if that is true it makes sense. But I am kind doubtful - I will explain why with an edit of my main-post. Maybe I just have gotten something wrong. Thank you nevertheless for this useful information :)

Comment: Okay - forget about it. I've just swapped information about the single-slit with the double-slit experiment and thus got a few things mixed. You are right. Thank you very much. I figured it out myself while trying to explain what I was thinking :)